# Recording Touchscreen Interactions in Android outside Application

Tags: java, android, analytics, android-sensors, touchscreen

Is it possible to create a service that collect touch screen interaction data? I have seen that this could be possible in earlier versions of Android but seems to be much more difficult to achieve now. I have found many questions on Stack Overflow that already attempt this solution but don't offer a solution. The problem is also outlined [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TKcC3Q9Ss6o&index=1).

I wish to record the x and y coordinates of each tap and swipe interaction for medical analytics of different user groups. This includes recording scrolling data in (for example) the web browser. So far I can't get it to do this outside of the default application. How can I build a service for this?

I have tried adapting the code [here](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/movement.html), but nothing seems to work outside the application when other applications are running.

Comment: This is not possible except on rooted devices or via a custom ROM, for privacy and security reasons. An accessibility service is the closest that you can get using the ordinary SDK, and that will not give you all that you are seeking.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you for your reply. So there's no way to do this? Can I ask the limitations of the accessibility service in regards to this?

Comment: AFAIK, the accessibility APIs do not provide low-level touch information. It is for interacting with widgets.

Comment: @CommonsWare Do you know if this is possible to do if the device is rooted?

Comment: I presume that there is a way to get at low-level touch information (e.g., from Linux drivers), but the details are outside my area of expertise.